# Where do I place a 301 redirect when using ColdFusion?

Tags: redirect, coldfusion

I found this code for 301 redirects in ColdFusion:

```
<cfheader statuscode="301" statustext="Moved Permanently">
<cfheader name="Location" value="[the URL to be redirected to]">
<cfabort>
```

What file do I place this code in? Is it the "missing page" that is now supposed to be giving a 301 error when someone lands on it? Or is there a file that's similar to .htaccess that I should put it in?

Comment: <cflocation> will do that cleaner.  Can you clarify better what you are trying to do though?  Is there a specific URL you are trying to redirect?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to redirect one specific URL to another specific URL. For example, if I need to redirect page.cfm to new-page.cfm, where should I place the <cflocation> code? In the page.cfm file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: 3xx status codes are not errors but redirects.

Your code snippet isn't wrong, but ColdFusion has a more comfy way to do these 3 lines with a single statement:

`<cflocation url="[the URL to be redirected to]" statusCode="301">`

You can put this tag anywhere in your .cfm template. ColdFusion executes everything up to this point and then stops execution, sets the response header accordingly, discards the output buffer (because 3xx are not supposed to contain a body) and transmits the response (header with location reference).

Note: Your code snippet would include content in the response body (e.g. everything you put in `<cfoutput>` tags), which is usually not desired. So I strongly recommend to use the `cflocation` tag for common redirects. It'll also protect you from forgetting to place `<cfabort>` after it.

---

For a common scenario like "redirect visitor from a no longer existing page to a new page", you can simply do this:

**no_longer_existing_page.cfm**

`<cflocation url="the_new_page.cfm" statusCode="301" addToken="false">`

**the_new_page.cfm**

```
<cfoutput>Hello World !!</cfoutput>
```

Requests to both pages will now point to `the_new_page.cfm` and return `Hello World !!`. *(This is a redirect, not a rewrite, so the address in the browser will change to `the_new_page.cfm` in both cases.)*

Comment: Thank you for all of the useful info.

I think I understand better now about implementing 301 redirects with ColdFusion; however, I am still unsure where to place `<cflocation url="[the URL to be redirected to]" statusCode="301">`, specifically which file.

For example, if I am trying to redirect page.cfm to new-page.cfm, would I place that cflocation code in the page.cfm file? Or does it go somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, you put the location request in the file that is supposed to redirect to the destination file. Do you simply need a permanent redirect for a page that does no longer exist and is supposed to go to a different page now?

Comment: Yes, that's all I need for now. Sorry for the elementary questions - this is my first time working with a site that's built with ColdFusion, and in the context of implementing redirects, I'm more familiar with .htaccess. I appreciate the help.